# Does electron-builder minify code or do I have to do that myself?

Tags: electron, minify, electron-builder

My electron application is getting bigger and bigger, with lots of HTML, JS and CSS source files. What I need to know is if when creating the distribution with [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) by running `yarn dist`, the JS/CSS files are minified?

Do I have to do this before myself if it's worth it? Can I add this middle step in here?

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron .",
  "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
  "dist": "electron-builder",
  "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
},
```

I use Visual Studio Code and could use Gulp but I need to know if there's some other method most people use, if they do care about minifying/obfuscating code. I would prefer not to separate my scripts into two folders and minify from one to another. Maybe there's a tool that does this at creating the distribution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code isn't minified, as said in [this issue comment](https://github.com/mattermost/desktop/issues/387#issuecomment-265432205), so you have to minify it yourself using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) for example.